# Tabs on BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I did a bottomnavigationview with two tabs, then I injected fragments at each of the tabs, I would like to know how to communicate the 2 tabs.
for example, creating an EditText with a button at the first tabs and then retrieving the information at the level of this tab and injecting it into a TextView at the level of the second.
I already tried with the bundle but it did not work when I click on the tabs that must retrieve the information the app stops showing "unfortunately appname has stopped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not recommended to use BottomNavigation with just 2 tabs. Use Tabs instead. [Read more](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage).
2. To communicate between fragments in one activity, just use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) from [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/).

Tips:

1. Follow the guidance here on how to share ViewModel data between fragments in one activity. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)
2. In the first fragment, bind the the EditText to LiveData.
3. In the second fragment, observe the LiveData and show it to TextView.